# Mapping exception using Stof/Gedmo Translation

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1

I'm migrating my Symfony 2.0 project to version 2.1rc1. After installing the `stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle` and the `gedmo/doctrine-extensions` and test my application I get the following error:

> No identifier/primary key specified for Entity "Company\TestBundle\Entity\PageTranslation" sub class of "Gedmo\Translatable\Entity\MappedSuperclass\AbstractTranslation". Every Entity must have an identifier/primary key.

My `config.yml` looks like this:

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:        
        driver:   %database_driver%
        host:     %database_host%
        port:     %database_port%
        dbname:   %database_name%
        user:     %database_user%
        password: %database_password%
        charset:  UTF8                    

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%        
        connection: default
        auto_mapping: true        
        mappings:
            gedmo_translatable:
                type: annotation
                prefix: Gedmo\Translatable\Entity
                dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Translatable/Entity"
                alias: GedmoTranslatable # this one is optional and will default to the name set for the mapping
                is_bundle: false
            gedmo_translator:
                type: annotation
                prefix: Gedmo\Translator\Entity
                dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Translator/Entity"
                alias: GedmoTranslator # this one is optional and will default to the name set for the mapping
                is_bundle: false

stof_doctrine_extensions:
    default_locale: en
    translation_fallback: true
    orm:
        default:               
            translatable: true
            sluggable: true
```

According to the [documentation of `StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle`](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.rst) this should be fine. The only thing I'm not sure of is the `auto_mapping: true` option.

The only code I've changed in my project is in my `CategoryTranslation class`. I've replaced:

```
use Stof\DoctrineExtensionsBundle\Entity\AbstractTranslation;
```

by:

```
use Gedmo\Translatable\Entity\MappedSuperclass\AbstractTranslation;
```

Because the Stof-bundle doesn't have an `AbstractTranslation` class anymore.

Can someone tell me how I can fix this?

Comment: Ok, so apparently my translation entities are also being processed when running 
    
    php app/console doctrine:generate:entities 
on the commandline. So how do I set my mappings to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Please add the PageTranslation class/mapping

Answer (score 0):

My PageTranslation entity before:

```
class PageTranslation extends AbstractTranslation
{
    /**
     * All required columns are mapped through inherited superclass
     */
}
```

My PageTranslation entity after generating the entities on the commandline:

```
class PageTranslation extends AbstractTranslation
{
    /**
     * All required columns are mapped through inherited superclass
     */

    /**
     * @var integer $id
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string $locale
     */
    private $locale;

    .....etc....

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set locale
     *
     * @param string $locale
     * @return PageTranslation
     */
    public function setLocale($locale)
    {
        $this->locale = $locale;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get locale
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getLocale()
    {
        return $this->locale;
    }

    ..etc....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using StofDoctrineExtensions you don't need `gedmo/doctrine-extensions`. Also isn't necessary to generate anything in PageTranslation